# Derivative of Pressure and Temperature over depth

Tags: r, spline, derivative

I am currently trying to create derivative curves for pressure temperature surveys of wells my company owns. However I had written a code to help me along in this process but have come to the realization something broke along the way. The code is cited below. However when I calculate the derivative of the normal pressure and temperature curves in a separate program I see a very stark contrast to the data. Linked in Image 1, the depths in the image are not the real depths, however the data is obviously quite different.

Left is derivative calculated in a separate program, right is calculated by R

[image]
    #Up Curves
    #read EXCEL
    h<-as.data.frame(read_excel("PLT.xlsx",sheet = "UP"))

```
#setting boundaries for curves
xs<-seq(round(min(h[["Depth MD"]]),0),round(max(h[["Depth MD"]]),0),by=0.5)
final<-data.frame(depth=xs,Press=1:length(xs),Temp=1:length(xs))
final[,"Press"]<-spline(h[["Depth MD"]],h[,"Pressure"],xout=xs)$y
final[,"Temp"]<-spline(h[["Depth MD"]],h[,"Temp"],xout=xs)$y

#Derivative Pressure
spfun<-splinefun(final$depth,final$Press)
final[["PDeriv"]]<-spfun(final$Press,deriv = 1)


#Derivative Temperature
spfun2<-splinefun(final$depth,final$Temp)
final[["TDeriv"]]<-spfun2(final$Temp,deriv=1)

#Plotting Values temp and Press
#Temp<-ggplot(final,aes(Temp))+geom_point(aes(y=depth),col="red")+
#    scale_y_reverse()+#limits=c(6000,5000)
#    scale_x_continuous()+theme_bw()#limits=c(90,110)
#Press<-ggplot(final,aes(Press))+geom_point(aes(y=depth),col="blue")+
#    scale_y_reverse()+theme_bw()
#grid.arrange(Temp,Press,ncol=2)

#Plotting Values Derivatives
#PDeriv<-ggplot(final,aes(PDeriv))+geom_point(aes(y=depth),col="purple")+
#  scale_y_reverse()+theme_bw()
#TDeriv<-ggplot(final,aes(TDeriv))+geom_point(aes(y=depth),col="purple")+
#  scale_y_reverse()+theme_bw()
#grid.arrange(TDeriv,PDeriv,ncol=2)


#what file would you like to write?
write.csv(final,file="PT_full_curves_UP.csv",row.names = F)
```

The excel spreadsheet I am using contains two sheets one for the "UP" pass and one for the "DOWN" pass. However the code is identical and I have only included one for the up.

So my question is did I mess up what I am doing with the deriv function in R? Or am I referencing something that isn't what I think it is. Also I am only looking for a first order derivative of the Pressure/Depth and Temperature/Depth.

Comment: thanks for the tip on passing the depth into the spfun and spfun2. I hadn't even thought about what needed to go into the derivation of the pressure and temperature. I guess I had been thinking about it backward and inserted the pressure and temperature in the final derivation instead of depth. Turning the function to derive the same values. Thanks.